# add new values to exsting variable in jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

i have a variable in jquery. first am adding some values to it.
now again am adding some more values to existing variable.
here is my code. if any one know help me......

```
var eventToAdd = {
                        title: $("#txtSubject").val(),
                        description: $("#addEventDesc").val(),
                        start: $("#txtStartdate").val(),
                        end: $("#txtEnddate").val()
                    };
                    var ChkBox = document.getElementById("rbtnHourly");
                    if (ChkBox.checked == true) {
                         **eventToAdd = {**
                            FREQ: "Hourly",
                            INTERVAL: $("#updown").val(),
                            BYSETPOS: "",
                            BYDAY: "",
                            BYMONTH: "",
                            BYMONTHDAY: ""
                        };
                    }
                    var ChkBox = document.getElementById("rbtnDaily");
                    if (ChkBox.checked == true) {
                        var rbtnEveryday = document.getElementById("rbtnEveryday");
                        if (rbtnEveryday.checked == true) {
                            **eventToAdd  = {**
                                FREQ: "Daily",
                                INTERVAL: $("#TextBox1").val(),
                                BYSETPOS: "",
                                BYDAY: "MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA,SU",
                                BYMONTH: "",
                                BYMONTHDAY: ""
                            };
                        }
                        else {
                           **var eventToAdd1 = {**
                                FREQ: "Daily",
                                INTERVAL: 1,
                                BYSETPOS: "",
                                BYDAY: "MO,TU,WE,TH,FR",
                                BYMONTH: "",
                                BYMONTHDAY: ""
                            };
                        };
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking but take a look at `jQuery.extend()`

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

This enables you to extend an object with other values

Answer (score 0):

You add values to an existing object by assigning to properties to it like this:

```
if (ChkBox.checked) {
    eventToAdd.FREQ = "Hourly";
    eventToAdd.INTERVAL = $("#updown").val();
    eventToAdd.BYSETPOS = "";
    eventToAdd.BYDAY = "";
    eventToAdd.BYMONTH = "";
    eventToAdd.BYMONTHDAY = "";
}
```